# Does $\sum _{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\pi \left(n\right)}}{n}$ converge, where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Does $\sum _{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\pi \left(n\right)}}{n}$ converge, where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function?

The resulting sum should look like
$$\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{11}-\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{13}-\cdots$$

So the sign of each fraction in the sequence switches whenever a prime is reached.

Comment: I have computed some partial sums and they are not too far from $1.3$, if that helps something.

Comment: Asked and unanswered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707870/the-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1-pinn?rq=1 Hopefully we'll get an answer now, though I doubt it.

Comment: Were this series to converge, then the following series would also converge, by regrouping the terms: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{i=p_k}^{p_{k+1}} \frac{(-1)^k}{i}$, where $(p_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is the sequence of primes. I don't have a full proof yet, but I think this is unlikely because the term$ \sum_{i=p_k}^{p_{k+1}} \frac{1}{i}$ can correspond to an arbitrarily large portion of the harmonic series

Comment: @Max But those arbitrarily large portions of the harmonic series are formed by even more arbitrarily small numbers.

Comment: @ajotatxe : yes, that's why my proof doesn't really work (I was writing it down when I realized this)

Comment: With a $30$ digits precision for each term,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{10^8}\frac{(-1)^{\pi(k)}}k\approx 1.29518551496576405122403560288$$

Comment: The sums $\displaystyle \sum_{i=p_{k-1}}^{p_k-1} \frac{1}{i}$ converge to $0$ by the [result of Guido Hoheisel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_Hoheisel) which implies that for each $\alpha>1$ for sufficiently large $k$: $p_{k+1} - p_k < \alpha \cdot p_k$. So the problem seems tough.

Comment: @Adayah so my intuition was completely false. Indeed, if there is no obvious divergence, it seems tough

Comment: Correction: I meant for each $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: People are absurdly quick to vote to close questions like this. This is certainly not a homework problem, and it's obvious that OP can't "show his or her work" when a problem like this is almost certainly beyond anything taught in standard undergraduate analysis/number theory courses.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Where do you see votes to close as homework? Somebody might be "absurdly quick" to slander other users here...

Comment: @Did Well, when you click "close" you can see the various options people voted for. A few people did indeed vote to close for lack of context.

Comment: @Mathematics There are a lot of other ways to provide context without providing your attempts (even though OP can provide his failed attempts no matter how hard the problem is), I probably wouldn't vote to close this question as off topic but still there is a reason.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 And the deciding vote to close is a vote to close as a duplicate. Let me suggest you save your expressions of outrage for worthier causes.